# How to pronounce '-ing' followed by a vowel

Tags: pronunciation, american-english, vowels, ing

I'm getting into English recently and I'm a little confused by the way people pronounce a word that starts in a vowel right after a word ending in *-ing*.

For example:

> You have to **bring it** up now?

I don't know if I should pronounce it as:

1. bring /ŋit/
2. brin' /nit/
3. bring /git/

Another example would be "I'm **coming out**".

Likewise, what about the ending *-ang*? For example:

> We can just **hang out** and have a good time.

And to round it all up, what about a combination of the two? For example,

> He got sick of **hanging around** waiting for you and went home.

I've been asking myself these questions for weeks.

Comment: Some people from New York City and the surrounding areas insert a /g/ after /ŋ/ if a vowel follows—Google *"Lawn Guyland"* (= *Long Island*). The vast majority of English speakers don't do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some English accents pronounce the *g* on the end of words like *bring* (even without a word following). The BrE Birmingham/Black Country accent can do this, for example, and I’m sure there are others. In this case, *bring it* would be pronounced /briŋgit/.

“Standard” English pronunciation does not insert the final /g/ and would use /briŋit/.

The same applies to all words ending /ŋ/ followed by a vowel.

Where the final *g* is pronounced, it can be inserted in other cases too: *“speaking Latin”* would not have an /iŋgl/ in the middle in Standard English pronunciation but it could well do so in an accent which normally pronounces the final *g*.

Comment: And in accents where unstressed _-ing_ may be pronounced /ɪn/, it will be /ɪnɪt/, e.g. "giving it".

Comment: Thanks. So while unstressed -ing may be pronounced /in/, how should I know if -ing should be unstressed or not? Or I can generally unstress all the words who ends with -ing? e.g. "givin' up", "sneakin' around" or "comin' out"?

Comment: No, just do Standard English: pronounce everything with the "ng" sound (sorry can't do IPA on an iPad), without making it "n" or having the intrusive hard "g". Dropping or adding the "g" is non-standard.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, thank you so much @Andrew!